# Discrete optimization of weighted sum under constraint

Tags: optimization, algorithms, discrete-optimization

Let $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \geq 0$, $\;\;c_1, \dots, c_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $\;\;\gamma >0 $.

We are looking for the maximum of function $f$ with
$$
f(x) = x_1\lambda_1 + \dots + x_n\lambda_n
$$

where $x_i \in \{-1,1\}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$

under the constraint

$$
x_1c_1 + \dots + x_nc_n \geq \gamma
$$

For our problem approximately $n=50$.

**Is there an efficient algorithm as trying out all $2^n$ possibilities is not feasible?**

**EDIT 2015-04-12**

I corrected the constraint. Before correction they were

$$
x_1\lambda_1c_1 + \dots + x_n\lambda_nc_n \geq \gamma
$$

Comment: I think the NP-Hard 0-1 knapsack problem (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Definition ) can be reduced to this problem ( hint: c_i := - w_i / v_i ). So if you find an polynomial algorithm, you will have demonstrated that P = NP.

Answer (score 0):

In short, your problem is
\begin{align}
  \max ~&~ \lambda_1 x_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n x_n \\
  \mathrm{s.t.} ~&~ c_1 x_1 + \ldots + c_n x_n \geq \gamma \\
  &~ x_i \in \{-1, 1\}
\end{align}
Let $y_i = \frac{x_i + 1}{2}$. Then you can rewrite the problem as
\begin{align}
  \max ~&~ 2 \left(\lambda_1 y_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n y_n\right) - (\lambda_1 + \ldots+ \lambda_n) \\
  \mathrm{s.t.} ~&~ (-2 c_1) y_1 + \ldots + (-2 c_n) y_n \leq -(c_1 + \ldots c_n) - \gamma \\
  &~ y_i \in \{0, 1\}
\end{align}
Note that $\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n$ in the objective function does not depend on the values of the $y_i$. Thus, this formulation is equivalent to
\begin{align}
  \max ~&~ v_1 y_1 + \ldots + v_n y_n \\
  \mathrm{s.t.} ~&~ w_1 y_1 + \ldots + w_n y_n \leq W \\
  &~ y_i \in \{0, 1\}
\end{align}
if we set $v_i = 2 \lambda_i$, $w_i = -2 c_i$ and $W = -(c_1 + \ldots + c_n) - \gamma$. This is an ordinary knapsack problem.

Thus, you will (probably) not be able to find an algorithm which solves all instances exactly in polynomial time. However, there are a lot of solution techniques for the knapsack problem which provide optimal solution in reasonable time for most real life instances (see the link to Wikipedia posted by Maarten Hilferink).